# Serilog does not write to a file using LoggerFactory in .NET 5 Console App, produces no errors or output

Tags: .net-core, serilog

I'm trying to use Serilog's [`AddFile`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file) by way of [LoggerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) but I can't get it to do *anything*.

[This is my `appsettings.json`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file#appsettingsjson-configuration), unchanged from the getting started guide.

Here is what I have:

```cs
IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    //.SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Logs"))
    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Properties", "appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
    //.AddEnvironmentVariables()
    //.AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
    builder
        .AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
        .AddConsole()
        .AddDebug()
        .AddFile("log.txt"); //Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
});

ILogger<Program> logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

logger.LogTrace("Trace");
logger.LogInformation("Information");
logger.LogDebug("Debug");
logger.LogError("Error");
logger.LogCritical("Critical");
```

I see output in the console. I receive no errors. Even with the suggested addition of:

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```

From: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics

Comment: What kind of application host are you running? ASP .NET on IIS? Standalone Windows Service? Something else?

Comment: Where does `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` points to at runtime? The log file is going to be located there

Comment: .NET 5 Console App. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is in `bin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Serilog extension you're using ([Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file)) internally [writes to the file asynchronously](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file/blob/v2.0.0/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File/Microsoft/Extensions/Logging/FileLoggerExtensions.cs#L146) on a separate thread, and your application is terminating before Serilog had the chance to flush the logs to the file on disk ([which could take about ~2 seconds](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file/blob/v2.0.0/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File/Microsoft/Extensions/Logging/FileLoggerExtensions.cs#L152)).

Normally you'd use an [application host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) that takes care of disposing the logger (and other services) before the application terminates, forcing a flush which would write to disk, but in your case with a simple Console app, nobody is disposing the log so there's no final flush happening before the app terminates.

Serilog has a [`Log.CloseAndFlush`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers) method that is normally used in cases like this and you're expected to call it before your app terminates, however [`Log.CloseAndFlush`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers) doesn't work with [Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file) (at least with the latest version as of this writing) because it doesn't assign the logger it creates to `Log.Logger` which is what `CloseAndFlush` tries to dispose.

Thus, in your case, without a host and without the ability to use `CloseAndFlush`, you'd need to prevent your application from terminating for a few seconds, for example, by blocking the main thread with a `Thread.Sleep` or wait for user input with a `Console.ReadLine`, or similar...

```
// ...
logger.LogError("Error");
logger.LogCritical("Critical");

// Just for the sake of proving that the file is being written (not production code)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // <<<<<
```

---

Related issue: [Means to troubleshoot/debug logging? #48](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file/issues/48)

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async) you can do an explicit `CloseAndFlush()`.

Comment: I never actually use anything called `Log` in my code. So I guess I need some way to tell either `ILogger` or `ILoggerFactory` to `Dispose()`?

Comment: @Noah `CloseAndFlush` doesn't work with `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` (at least with the latest version as of this writing) because it doesn't assign the logger created to `Log.Logger` - which is what `CloseAndFlush` tries to dispose.

Comment: @BrianJenkins With the current implementation of `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` you can't get a reference to the log directly to dispose. You need an application host to do that for you.

Comment: Is there a workaround if I use a different Serilog package? Something that might give me more control?

Comment: @BrianJenkins Use an application host with [`Serilog.Extensions.Hosting`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting) so that you can call `Log.CloseAndFlush()` before the app ends.

Comment: Might be a good improvement to the first sentence to point out that it's only _Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File_ that writes asynchronously; the default `WriteTo.File()` in Serilog is fully synchronous/flushing.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Good point. Updated it to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
   // 1- Program.cs  
 
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            
            builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
            {
                // set Serilog configuration
            });
   // 2-
        using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(
            builder => builder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
    
   // 3-    
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger();
        
   //4-  
        logger.LogDebug("hello world");
```

from- https://habr.com/en/articles/591171/